# Hiding div based on data attribute value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two navigational arrows which are hidden or visible based on `data-count`.

- The `counter` starts from `0`
- If a user clicks on `arrow--right`, `counter` will be `+1` (the maximum value `counter` can have is `1`).
- If a user clicks on `arrow--left`, `counter` will be `-1` (the minimum value `counter` can have is `-1`).

Therefore, counter can either be `-1`, `0` or `1`.

Based on this:

- If `counter` is `-1`, I want to hide `arrow--left`.
- If `counter` is `0`, both arrows will be visible.
- If `counter` is `1`, I want to hide `arrow--right`.

Here is my current approach which isn't yielding the results described above:

```js
$(function() {

  var counter = 0;
  $(".arrow--right").on("click", function() {
    counter++;
    $(this).attr('data-count', counter);
    console.log(counter);
  });

  $(".arrow--left").on("click", function() {
    counter--;
    $(this).attr('data-count', counter);
    console.log(counter);
  });

});
```

```css
.flex{
  display: flex;
}

.arrow{
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow--right[data-counter"=1"]{
  display: none;
}

.arrow--left[data-counter="-1"]{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="flex">
  <div class="arrow arrow--left">Left</div>
  <div class="arrow arrow--right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: looks like multiple typos ... misplaced `"` and a couple extra letters at the end of the data-count :p

Answer (score 0):

`.arrow--right[data-counter"=1"]` is missing a `=`, and checks whether the `data-counter` attribute is `-1`. You should be checking the `data-count` attribute instead, and the value should be `1`.

So your selector should be:

```css
.arrow--right[data-count="1"]
```

```js
$(function() {

  var counter = 0;
  $(".arrow--right").on("click", function() {
    counter++;
    $(this).attr('data-count', counter);
    console.log(counter);
  });

  $(".arrow--left").on("click", function() {
    counter--;
    $(this).attr('data-count', counter);
    console.log(counter);
  });

});
```

```css
.flex{
  display: flex;
}

.arrow{
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow--right[data-count="1"]{
  display: none;
}

.arrow--left[data-count="-1"]{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="flex">
  <div class="arrow arrow--left">Left</div>
  <div class="arrow arrow--right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Spectric,  your demo successfully hides the arrows, but as above, if `counter` is `0`, both arrows should be visible and if `counter` is `-1`, only `.arrow--left` should be hidden (`.arrow--right` should still be visible).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. I adjusted the script and classes as well as fixed a CSS typo.

this is using your code with the CSS classes. I would recommend just adding a class like $(".arrow--right").addClass('notVisible'); to remove them and then just use .removeClass to make it visible again. Makes it a bit easier, you don't need to increment things all the time in the attributes.

```js
$(function() {

  var counter = 0;
  $(".arrow").on("click", function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('arrow--right')){
        counter++;
    } else {
        counter--;
    }
    if(counter >= 1){
        $(".arrow--right").attr('data-counter', '1');
    } else {
        $(".arrow--right").attr('data-counter', counter);
    }
    if(counter <= -1){
        $(".arrow--left").attr('data-counter', '-1');
    } else {
        $(".arrow--left").attr('data-counter', counter);
    }
    console.log(counter);
  });

});
```

```css
.flex{
  display: flex;
}

.arrow{
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow--right[data-counter="1"]{
  display: none;
}

.arrow--left[data-counter="-1"]{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="flex">
  <div class="arrow arrow--left">Left</div>
  <div class="arrow arrow--right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

define a function and use that in arrows events.

```js
$(function() {

      var counter = 0;
      
      $(".arrow--right").on("click", function() {
        counter++;
        $(this).attr('data-count', counter);
        show_hide_arrow(counter);
        console.log(counter);
      });

      $(".arrow--left").on("click", function() {
        counter--;
        $(this).attr('data-count', counter);
        show_hide_arrow(counter);
        console.log(counter);
      });

      function show_hide_arrow(counter)
      {
          if( parseInt(counter) == -1 )
          {
            $(".arrow--left").prop('hidden',true)
            
          } else if( parseInt(counter) == 1 )
          {
            $(".arrow--right").prop('hidden',true)
          } else
          {
            $(".arrow--right").prop('hidden',false)
            $(".arrow--left").prop('hidden',false)
          }
       }
  })
```

```css
    .flex{
      display: flex;
    }

    .arrow{
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .arrow--right[data-counter"=1"]{
      display: none;
    }

    .arrow--left[data-counter="-1"]{
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex">
      <div class="arrow arrow--left">Left</div>
      <div class="arrow arrow--right">Right</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data counter is at a wrong place..

```js
const flexCounter = document.querySelector('.flex')

flexCounter.onclick = ({target}) =>
  {
  if (!target.matches('.arrow')) return

  flexCounter.dataset.counter = 
        parseInt(flexCounter.dataset.counter)
      + (target.matches('.arrow--left') ? -1 : +1 )
  }
```

```css
/* data-counter must be on .flex element ) */
.flex[data-counter="1"] .arrow--right,
.flex[data-counter="-1"] .arrow--left {
  /* display : none; */ 
  visibility : hidden;  /* prefer to use visibility  ? */
  }

.flex{
  display     : flex;
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 14px;
  }
.flex::before {   /* show counter  value ...? */
  display       : inline-block;
  width         : 2em;
  border-radius : .5em;
  background    : yellow;
  content       : attr(data-counter);
  color         : darkblue;
  font-weight   : bold;
  text-align    : center;
  padding-top   : .3em;
  margin-right  : .5em; 
  }
.arrow{
  padding       : .3em;
  border        : 1px solid darkblue;
  cursor        : pointer;
  border-radius : .5em;
  width         : 3em;
  text-align    : center;
  margin-left   : .5em;
  }
.arrow:hover {
  background : darkblue;
  color      : white;
  }
```

```html
<div class="flex" data-counter="0">
  <div class="arrow arrow--left">Left</div>
  <div class="arrow arrow--right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a separate function `toggleVisibility` to implement logic of show/hide based on counter value, and use `css(propertyName, value)` method of jQuery to set `visibility` css property.

```js
$(function() {
  let counter = 0;
  const rightArrow = $(".arrow--right");
  const leftArrow = $(".arrow--left");
  
  rightArrow.on("click", function() {
    counter++;
    toggleVisibility();
  });
  leftArrow.on("click", function() {
    counter--;
    toggleVisibility();
  });
  
  function toggleVisibility() {
    rightArrow.css("visibility", "visible");
    leftArrow.css("visibility", "visible");
    if (counter > 0) {
      rightArrow.css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
    if (counter < 0) {
      leftArrow.css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
    $("#counter").text(counter); // test purpose only...
  }

});
```

```css
.flex{
  display: flex;
}

.arrow{
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#counter {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #1E7FE7;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="flex">
  <div class="arrow arrow--left">Left</div>
  <div class="arrow arrow--right">Right</div>
</div>
<div id="counter">0</div>
```